# Why running the same R lm code gives different results?

Tags: r, lm

For some reason, running a lm regression in R gave me different output. It is a simple lm and no randomness is involved. And because I only got this weird result in my computer (the code gave the same results on other computers), I did not attach the data here; instead, I attached the outputs.

Does anyone have suggestions?? Thanks!

```r
d = read.csv("d.csv")
str(d)
## 'data.frame':    5000 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ elevation_sd: num  -0.6123 1.3988 -0.111 -0.0763 0.4129 ...
##  $ pred_rich   : num  6.74 10.35 10.81 15.24 37.58 ...
coef(lm(pred_rich ~ elevation_sd + I(elevation_sd^2), data = d))
##       (Intercept)      elevation_sd I(elevation_sd^2) 
##       31.40967132      -14.51366622       -0.04686489
coef(lm(pred_rich ~ elevation_sd + I(elevation_sd^2), data = d))
##       (Intercept)      elevation_sd I(elevation_sd^2) 
##         24.791451        -22.377711          2.530645
coef(lm(pred_rich ~ elevation_sd + I(elevation_sd^2), data = d))
##       (Intercept)      elevation_sd I(elevation_sd^2) 
##         29.009348        -24.539297          2.184579
coef(lm(pred_rich ~ elevation_sd + I(elevation_sd^2), data = d))
##       (Intercept)      elevation_sd I(elevation_sd^2) 
##         17.615122        -36.893819          5.300316
coef(lm(pred_rich ~ elevation_sd + I(elevation_sd^2), data = d))
##       (Intercept)      elevation_sd I(elevation_sd^2) 
##         17.292353        -37.052702          5.461568
```

```
## R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_rt.so
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] digest_0.6.29   R6_2.5.1        jsonlite_1.8.0  magrittr_2.0.3 
##  [5] evaluate_0.15   stringi_1.7.8   cachem_1.0.6    rlang_1.0.4    
##  [9] cli_3.3.0       rstudioapi_0.13 jquerylib_0.1.4 bslib_0.4.0    
## [13] rmarkdown_2.14  tools_4.2.1     stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.31      
## [17] yaml_2.3.5      fastmap_1.1.0   compiler_4.2.1  htmltools_0.5.3
## [21] knitr_1.39      sass_0.4.2
```

Comment: Please do a) not post images, but copy and paste (and format, it's easy with markdown) code and b) make it reproducible.  We do not have your data, so all we have is an anecdote.

Comment: As I mentioned, you likely cannot reproduce what I got because with the same data and code, I cannot reproduce it on my other laptop.

Comment: You just said that the code gives the same result on other computers. We cannot really help in this case since the problem is not reproducible. Consider restarting your R kernel

Comment: Already cleared workspace and done that multiple times. Just want to hear about potential reasons for such behavior.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd get different results unless you have somehow loaded something in your R profile or somewhere that changes `d` each time it's accessed. What if you run `d1 = read.csv("d.csv")` and then run with `data = d1`?

Comment: If you run just `d` twice does it output the same data?

Comment: Yes they are the same, `d` did not change. @JonSpring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing my BLAS/LAPACK.

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I selected OpenBLAS and then restarted R, no issue anymore! I have also tried the default BLAS/LAPACK and the AtlasBLAS, both work too!

So, the issue is from the Intel MLK libraries! Thanks @dirk-eddelbuettel for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in the comment I made, this is at most an anecdote, and likely a waste of your and our time.  We cannot do *anything* meaningful without a reproducible example.

But we can mock this.  Here I make a random draw, also with `N = 5000` as in your case, and run the regression five times.  Needless to say, even with these two vectors with no association whatsover *by design* the *purely numerically determined coefficients are **of course** identical*.

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- rnorm(5000); y <- rnorm(5000)  # your dimensions
> replicate(5, lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))$coef)
                   [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
(Intercept) -0.01371532 -0.01371532 -0.01371532 -0.01371532 -0.01371532
x           -0.00613063 -0.00613063 -0.00613063 -0.00613063 -0.00613063
I(x^2)       0.00964436  0.00964436  0.00964436  0.00964436  0.00964436
>
```

Now, those three lines of code *are* reproducible so I invite you to run this on your system.

*Edit:* My `sessionInfo()`, also on Ubuntu but 22.04, starts with *two* lines for BLAS and LAPACK.  You only have one which does not seem right.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0
```

Comment: Indeed, it is the BLAS/LAPACK!! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you are sorted out. The standard way to signal that on StackOverflow would be to upvote an answer (click on the "up" triangle") and/or to accept it (click on the "tick" mark).  That is how better answers get signaled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got by running Dirk's code:

```
                   [,1]        [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
(Intercept)  0.01103854  0.01819024 -0.010350210  0.01828507  0.02242858
x           -0.02816530 -0.05002762 -0.027738397 -0.02812795 -0.02775974
I(x^2)      -0.01918489 -0.01735535 -0.005590314 -0.01720919 -0.01929609
```

To make the output more different:

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(5000) 
y <- x + x^2 + rnorm(5000)  
replicate(5, lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))$coef)
```

```
                 [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
(Intercept) -1.643336 -3.908215 -1.979385 -3.707418 -1.845149
x            2.033474  2.001891  2.019949  2.007776  2.045030
I(x^2)       1.834672  1.977397  1.995412  2.867048  1.936577
```

See the fourth replication have very different coefs.

And the output below is from my other laptop (which works as expected):

```
(Intercept) -0.01371532 -0.01371532 -0.01371532 -0.01371532 -0.01371532
x            0.99386937  0.99386937  0.99386937  0.99386937  0.99386937
I(x^2)       1.00964436  1.00964436  1.00964436  1.00964436  1.00964436
```

Comment: Something is not quite right on your system, and it is not something I have seen in 25+ years with R.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think something is really messed up but not sure about what. I may need to uninstall and reinstall R, or potentially the whole OS.

Comment: What if you run `replicate(5, stats::lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))$coef)`? Maybe you have overwritten `lm` with a variation that alters the input?

Comment: No luck. I also have just completely uninstall and reinstall R, still not solved. This is so weird. I may need to reinstall my OS, such a pain.

Comment: Don't panic yet. You provided helpful info via `sessionInfo()`.  Maybe all you need to do is to uninstall the MKL and/or prefer a trusted one such as OpenBLAS or Atlas. See the edit to my answer.